# ZOD discriminateUnion based on two discriminator fields

Tags: typescript, zod

I have a schema with two fields I would like to discriminate based on:

```
enum Action = {
    CREATE: 'create'
}

enum ObjectType = {
    Potatoe: 'potatoe',
    Tomatoe: 'tomatoe'
}

export const TestSchema = z.object({
  action: z.nativeEnum(Action),
  objectType: z.nativeEnum(ObjectType),
  payload: // discriminate based on combination of `action` and `objectType`,
});
```

In the example above (simplified) I would like to discriminate the type of the `payload` based on the combination of the two keys `action` and `objectType`.

`discriminatedUnion` [[ref](https://zod.dev/?id=discriminated-unions)] Seems to only allow discrimination by one field

Comment: `z.discriminatedUnion` is indeed limited to a single key, but it's only for parsing efficiency and better error messages. There's a few open GitHub issues about it, but until then you can still create a multi-key discriminated union by using `z.union`.